# Cannot have function with generic parameter in generic stateful widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I was trying to create a generic stateful widget in flutter with a parameter as a function with a generic parameter like this:-

```dart
class MyWidget<T> extends StatefulWidget {
  MyWidget(
    {this.fn}
  );
  
  final void Function(T value)? fn;
  
  @override
  _MyWidgetState createState() => _MyWidgetState<T>();
}

class _MyWidgetState<T> extends State<MyWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text('Hello, World! ${widget.fn == null}');
  }
}
```

Which I then called like this:-

```dart
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget<double>(
            fn: (_) {},
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

But this does not produce any output, can anyone help me? This works perfectly fine in case of `Stateless` Widget and in case `fn` value is `null`.

Comment: Please check this link - https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues/4033#issuecomment-547909204

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because _MyWidgetState doesn't know how to parameterize the type of its parent widget, so when you try to use widget.fn, the runtime is unable to resolve the type correctly.

To fix it, try this:

```
class _MyWidgetState<T> extends State<MyWidget<T>> {
                                              ^^^
```

Instead of this

```
class _MyWidgetState<T> extends State<MyWidget> {
```